# If $t \to \lVert f(\cdot,t) \rVert_{L^2_x}^2$ is absolutely continuous, can we interchange the spatial integtal and time derivative?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, absolute-continuity, bochner-spaces

Let $f(x,t) : S^1 \times [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that

1. $f(x,t) \in L^q_t\bigl([0,\infty), L^p_x(S^1)\bigr)$
2. $\partial_t f(x,t) \in L^{q'}_t\bigl([0,\infty), L^{p'}_x(S^1)\bigr)$. Here the time derivative is weak one in the context of Bochner spaces.

where $p,p' \in (1,\infty)$ satisfy $1/p+1/p'=1$ but $q, q' \in (1,\infty)$ are just $1/q + 1/q' >1$.

However, suppose additionally that $t \to \lVert f(\cdot,t) \rVert_{L^2_x}^2$ is in fact "absolutely continuous".

Then, is it true that
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}\lVert f(\cdot,t) \rVert_{L^2_x}^2= 2\int_{S^1} f(x,t) \partial_t f(x,t) dx
\end{equation}
for a.e. $t \in [0,\infty)$?

I tried to prove this myself using Aubin-Lions lemma somehow, but things do not work for me since $q,q'$ are not conjugate exponents for now.

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: @LorenzoPompili So, my question essentially comes down to whether or not we can improve $1/q+1/q'$ to $1$ from absolute continuity of $t \to \lVert f(\cdot,t) \rVert_{L^2_x}^2$.

Comment: If $p’\geq 2$, then $f$ is automatically absolutely continuous with values in $L^2$, and the statement looks true. The hard case is when $p’<2$, i.e., $p>2$. In that case, I don’t know if the statement is true

Comment: @LorenzoPompili Could you tell me why $p' \geq 2$ implies that the statement is true?

Comment: @LorenzoPompili And yes, $p'<2$ is the case I am faced with at the moment..

Comment: Cause since $L^{p’}\subset L^2$, then $\partial_t f\in L^{q’}_t L^2_x$, and integrating in time it should follow that $f$ is in $C^{0,\alpha}_tL^2_x$ with $\alpha=1-1/q’$, assuming $f|_{t=0}$ lies in $L^2$ (which does, thanks to the additional assumption on the $L^2$ norm). Sorry, I have no clue about $p>2$, it is a good question. I have never encountered such a situation in PDE applications so far